# SwitchPreference and CheckBoxPreference in code

Tags: java, android, xml, android-preferences

I am now creating a preference page for my app

After API-14, switchpreference is available. and i would like to use it to replace checkboxpreference on API14+ devices

It is easy to use `res/xml` and `res/xml-14` to get the correct xml resource

However, in the coding part, it is not so convenient to switching the preference according to the API.

```
public class SettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private CheckBoxPreference enable;
    private SwitchPreference enablev14;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14)
            enable = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(key_enable);
        else
            enablev14 = (SwitchPreference) findPreference(key_enable);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now my way is to use if-clause to check the `Build.VERSION` and get the corresponding object to process it.
But it is quite inconvenient and hard to manage the code.
Do anyone has a smarter way to do it?

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you could set an `android:key` attribute to both of your SwitchPreference and CheckBoxPreference xml, just like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="pref_sync"
        android:title="@string/pref_sync"
        android:defaultValue="true" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="pref_sync"
        android:title="@string/pref_sync"
        android:defaultValue="true" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And then you can check if this key returns true or false on your code, something like this:

```
public class SettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting);
    PreferenceManager preferenceManager = getPreferenceManager();
    if (preferenceManager.getSharedPreferences().getBoolean("pref_sync", true)){
        // Your switch is on
    } else {
        // Your switch is off
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 6):

In your Java code use [`TwoStatePreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/TwoStatePreference.html), which is a parent class for both `CheckBoxPreference` and `SwitchPreference`.  It has all the methods you are likely to need in your use case.

This is what the code sample you provided would look like:

```
public class SettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private TwoStatePreference enable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting);
        enable = (TwoStatePreference) findPreference(key_enable);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: But TwoStatePreference was added in API level 14, so you cannot use it in the cases you need the CheckBoxPreference

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the code would want to do with the preference instance, it might be as simple as casting to `Preference` instead of a specific derived type, e.g.:

```
enable = (Preference)findPreference(key_enable);
```

which would then allow something like:

```
enable.setEnabled(true);
```

and eliminate the need to check API level in the code.